# Coverflow Carousel effect same as iPhone/iPad in android

Tags: android, carousel, coverflow

Please see the below carousel image.

[image]

In this carousel iPhone developers are showing images from Web Url. We have to do the same but I tried much more on the web and other I didn't get the exact effect and smoothness like iPad Cover flow in android. And even In my cover flow images are not displaying fastly. So please can you suggest any solution regarding the same.

Comment: @Sanat Pandey are u got it?

Answer (score 4):

I made a coverflow widget from scratch. It doesn't use any deprecated components. You can find it here:
https://github.com/applm/ma-components

Edit: This implementation of coverflow is broken on newer android versions. I deprecated it. You can take a look at https://github.com/applm/CarouselWidget

Comment: how to use this any demo example?

Answer (score 2):

Check out the 3D Carousel effects [HERE](https://code.google.com/p/android-3d-carousel-view/). Carousel Component is very useful when you need to visualize list style data effectively like in the Music player or Gallery application. It provides a sample also.

You can check out the [Demo](https://github.com/strider2023/Carousel-Android/tree/master/Carousel%20Android) also.

[image]

Comment: I want it for dynamic array of images. Do you know anything?

Comment: The GAMA Carousel link is broken