# Need help to find some kind of slider image like this?

Tags: android, ios, image

i'm still finding a library for this kind of slider in ios and android. It will save my days if someone share the source code or library for this.

When i try to slide left for right, new image will show up, but the image in nearby will be in another angle .

Some one please help me ?

[image]

Comment: On iOS this is known as a CoverFlow list. There is a framework called iCarosel that makes this easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For iOS good option is iCarousel. It can be downloaded here https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel . Display type cylinder seems very similar to presented image.

I'm not very familiar with Android, but this can be helpful:
https://github.com/Azoft/CarouselLayoutManager
Or something from this link: [Coverflow Carousel effect same as iPhone/iPad in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20677100/coverflow-carousel-effect-same-as-iphone-ipad-in-android) .

Generally, search for "carousel" for iOS and Android will give you many answers that can be useful.